# OneNote 2013 Bullet Indents

Tags: microsoft-onenote, bullets

OneNote 2013: I would like to stop my bullets from indenting. I would like them to be aligned the same as my to do check boxes. Is this possible? I have tried formatting them in MS Word and copying them, using different bullets, and even tried copying a non-indented bullet from another onenote template.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit Shift + Tab anytime you have a bullet and it will move left. You can also highlight a list of bullets and apply this method. If you are on a sub-bullet, it will go to the same format as it's parent. I don't think you can change a setting to make it not-indent by default.

Comment: Unfortunately using the Shift + Tab will also move all of the checkboxes in the following paragraphs to the left. :-(